# service with android:process doesn't start

Tags: android, service, process, manifest

I have simple app for testing android:process attribute of service. So my service looks like this:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    static final String TAG = "MyService";

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Log.d(TAG,"onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        doJob();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void doJob() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG,"job started");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i(TAG,"job stopped");

                stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to start service from the activity as follows:

```
findViewById(R.id.startServiceBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class));
            }
        });
```

All works fine. Now i'm adding android:process=":service" attribute to service declaration in the manifest. And after that service doesnt't start. So why so and what should i change for start service in separate process?

Comment: How did you check if your service runs?

Comment: It isn't your problem, but you're using intent service wrong.  You should not be doing anything in onStartCommand for an intent service-  it should all be in onHandleIntent.  By doing it in onStartCommand you're breaking the IntentService's built in method of handling requests.

Comment: @F43nd1r i'm checking it using android monitor tab in studio, service should start doJob() method which print messages to logcat. if i see these messages then it means that service is running

Comment: I updated code by adding log message from onCreate(). This message dont appear in logcat

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do this task i.e dowork() method call in onHandleIntent(). Because your service class extending Intent service instead of Service.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
static final String TAG = "MyService";

public MyService() {
    super("MyService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
 doJob();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


}

private void doJob() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG,"job started");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"job stopped");

            stopSelf();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

Comment: You're right that he's implementing it incorrectly, but that isn't his problem-  it will run the way he wrote it, it just won't handle intents correctly.

Comment: @Sandeep Kumar replacing doJob from onStartCommand to onHandleIntent doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

oh sorry it was silly mistake - i have to select new process in android monitor tab) thanks to all